# How to filter an array of objects and order them based on how many times they show up in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of user objects, some of which appear multiple times. I am trying to count how many times each unique user object shows up in the array and reorder them to make the user that appears most often be first in the array, and the user that appears least in the array show up last in the array.

```
const users = 
[
   {id: "0f933bbd-d1fb-4ad5-80f0-661c3c0aa2f8", handle: "lisa", email: "lisa@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894321997},
 
   {id: "bbfc927c-f3d4-4cdd-b872-9cb233a194aa", handle: "jisoo", email: "jisoo@gmail.com", createdAt: 1592452421714},

   {id: "be942039-6a59-46a4-9f92-1f7808b20c2f", handle: "unnieJennie", email: "jennie@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894227232},

   {id: "0f933bbd-d1fb-4ad5-80f0-661c3c0aa2f8", handle: "lisa", email: "lisa@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894321997},

   {id: "1d1e31cd-eff2-47de-b46d-4d45bb2dd97f", handle: "kawikaLovesKpop", email: "kawika@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894550566},

   {id: "be942039-6a59-46a4-9f92-1f7808b20c2f", handle: "unnieJennie", email: "jennie@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894227232},

   {id: "0f933bbd-d1fb-4ad5-80f0-661c3c0aa2f8", handle: "lisa", email: "lisa@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894321997},

   {id: "1d1e31cd-eff2-47de-b46d-4d45bb2dd97f", handle: "kawikaLovesKpop", email: "kawika@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894550566},

   {id: "be942039-6a59-46a4-9f92-1f7808b20c2f", handle: "unnieJennie", email: "jennie@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894227232}
]
```

I have tried using the method countBy with lodash

```
const bestMatched = countBy(users, "handle");
```

which returns

```
{lisa: 3, jisoo: 1, unnieJennie: 3, kawikaLovesKpop: 2}
```

I would still need access to the users array with all of the objects keys and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const users = 
[
   {id: "0f933bbd-d1fb-4ad5-80f0-661c3c0aa2f8", handle: "lisa", email: "lisa@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894321997},
 
   {id: "bbfc927c-f3d4-4cdd-b872-9cb233a194aa", handle: "jisoo", email: "jisoo@gmail.com", createdAt: 1592452421714},

   {id: "be942039-6a59-46a4-9f92-1f7808b20c2f", handle: "unnieJennie", email: "jennie@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894227232},

   {id: "0f933bbd-d1fb-4ad5-80f0-661c3c0aa2f8", handle: "lisa", email: "lisa@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894321997},

   {id: "1d1e31cd-eff2-47de-b46d-4d45bb2dd97f", handle: "kawikaLovesKpop", email: "kawika@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894550566},

   {id: "be942039-6a59-46a4-9f92-1f7808b20c2f", handle: "unnieJennie", email: "jennie@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894227232},

   {id: "0f933bbd-d1fb-4ad5-80f0-661c3c0aa2f8", handle: "lisa", email: "lisa@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894321997},

   {id: "1d1e31cd-eff2-47de-b46d-4d45bb2dd97f", handle: "kawikaLovesKpop", email: "kawika@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894550566},

   {id: "be942039-6a59-46a4-9f92-1f7808b20c2f", handle: "unnieJennie", email: "jennie@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894227232}
]

ob={lisa: 3, jisoo: 1, unnieJennie: 3, kawikaLovesKpop: 2}
map=new Map()
users.map(x=>map.set(x.handle,x))
res=Object.entries(ob).sort((a,b)=>b[1]-a[1])
.flatMap(o=>Array(o[1]).fill(map.get(o[0])))


console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bitwise [NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) to do this because `~undefined = -1` and we need an object to store our result:

```
const result = users.reduce((m,{handle})=>({...m, [handle]:-~m[handle]}), {})
```

Try it:

```js
const users = 
[
   {id: "0f933bbd-d1fb-4ad5-80f0-661c3c0aa2f8", handle: "lisa", email: "lisa@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894321997},
 
   {id: "bbfc927c-f3d4-4cdd-b872-9cb233a194aa", handle: "jisoo", email: "jisoo@gmail.com", createdAt: 1592452421714},

   {id: "be942039-6a59-46a4-9f92-1f7808b20c2f", handle: "unnieJennie", email: "jennie@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894227232},

   {id: "0f933bbd-d1fb-4ad5-80f0-661c3c0aa2f8", handle: "lisa", email: "lisa@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894321997},

   {id: "1d1e31cd-eff2-47de-b46d-4d45bb2dd97f", handle: "kawikaLovesKpop", email: "kawika@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894550566},

   {id: "be942039-6a59-46a4-9f92-1f7808b20c2f", handle: "unnieJennie", email: "jennie@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894227232},

   {id: "0f933bbd-d1fb-4ad5-80f0-661c3c0aa2f8", handle: "lisa", email: "lisa@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894321997},

   {id: "1d1e31cd-eff2-47de-b46d-4d45bb2dd97f", handle: "kawikaLovesKpop", email: "kawika@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894550566},

   {id: "be942039-6a59-46a4-9f92-1f7808b20c2f", handle: "unnieJennie", email: "jennie@gmail.com", createdAt: 1593894227232}
]

const result = users.reduce((m,{handle})=>({...m, [handle]:-~m[handle]}), {})

console.log({result})
```

Since object is not ordered so if you want to have a collection in order, you need to use array.

```
const result = users.reduce((m,{handle})=>({...m, [handle]:-~m[handle]}), {})
Object.keys(result).sort((a,b)=>result[a]-result[b]).map(key=>({[key]:result[key]}))
```

Comment: what ~ is doing there?

Comment: @MoHradA  basically, we will initialize an object `{}` and then we will count the occurrences of each element, if the key does not exist  before (undefined) then it should be 1 (with bitwise NOT we can do it like that ~undefined = -1 and -~undefined = 1), if the key exist then it should be the previous + 1

Comment: thanks, it's nice. since the OP wanted to sort the result, I suggest adding that logic too

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let counterObj = {}

for (user of users){
    counterObj[user.handle] = 1 + (counterObj[user.handle] || 0)
}

console.log(counterObj)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! This also returns the same solution as the countBy method above:

```
{lisa: 3, jisoo: 1, unnieJennie: 3, kawikaLovesKpop: 2}
```

I am trying to return another array with the users "lisa" and "unnieJennie" first since they appear 3 times,  "kawika" next because he appears twice, and "jisoo" last for she appears once.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this may be what you're looking for. There were some errors in the JSON as well, but it should be good now.

```
const users = [
  {
    id: '0f933bbd-d1fb-4ad5-80f0-661c3c0aa2f8',
    handle: 'lisa',
    email: 'lisa@gmail.com',
    createdAt: 1593894321997,
  },
  {
    id: 'bbfc927c-f3d4-4cdd-b872-9cb233a194aa',
    handle: 'jisoo',
    email: 'jisoo@gmail.com',
    createdAt: 1592452421714,
  },
  {
    id: 'be942039-6a59-46a4-9f92-1f7808b20c2f',
    handle: 'unnieJennie',
    email: 'jennie@gmail.com',
    createdAt: 1593894227232,
  },
  {
    id: '0f933bbd-d1fb-4ad5-80f0-661c3c0aa2f8',
    handle: 'lisa',
    email: 'lisa@gmail.com',
    createdAt: 1593894321997,
  },
  {
    id: '1d1e31cd-eff2-47de-b46d-4d45bb2dd97f',
    handle: 'kawikaLovesKpop',
    email: 'kawika@gmail.com',
    createdAt: 1593894550566,
  },
  {
    id: 'be942039-6a59-46a4-9f92-1f7808b20c2f',
    handle: 'unnieJennie',
    email: 'jennie@gmail.com',
    createdAt: 1593894227232,
  },
  {
    id: '0f933bbd-d1fb-4ad5-80f0-661c3c0aa2f8',
    handle: 'lisa',
    email: 'lisa@gmail.com',
    createdAt: 1593894321997,
  },
  {
    id: '1d1e31cd-eff2-47de-b46d-4d45bb2dd97f',
    handle: 'kawikaLovesKpop',
    email: 'kawika@gmail.com',
    createdAt: 1593894550566,
  },
  {
    id: 'be942039-6a59-46a4-9f92-1f7808b20c2f',
    handle: 'unnieJennie',
    email: 'jennie@gmail.com',
    createdAt: 1593894227232,
  },
];

function sort(jsonArray) {
  var containerArray = [];
  jsonArray.map((item, index) => {
    if (item === 'null') {
    } else {
      var newArray = [];
      var itemHandle = item.handle;
      jsonArray.map((i, index) => {
        if (itemHandle === i.handle && itemHandle !== 'null') {
          newArray.push(i);
          jsonArray.splice(index, 1, 'null');
        }
      });
      jsonArray.splice(index, 1, 'null');
      containerArray.push(newArray);
    }
  });
  return containerArray;
}

var finalArray = sort(users);

//Sorts the finalArray by highest occurrence to lowest
finalArray.sort(function(a,b){
  return b.length - a.length
})

console.log(finalArray)
```

Keeps objects together so that you can still access their properties via dot notation.

Comment: Splicing array being looped over is a really bad practice. Also you seem to use map where find or forEach would be more practical. Using map() just to create a loop is also a poor practice

Comment: @charlietfl What should be used in place of splice?